# Change order of tasks which are assigned to a user in VSTS

Tags: azure-devops, task

How can I change the order of tasks which are assigned to one user, so he/she knows which one to start with/which has the highest priority?

We can change the order of epics/feature/user stories in the backlogs, the order of tasks in a user story, all simply by dragging. But not in the task board?

[image]

31-10-2018 Update for anyone who's interested: I found a popup-message in the old view of VSTS which states that it is not possible, when grouped by people. Concluding: there is no order per person possible.

[Old view with warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBa1b.png)

Answer (score 0):

Based on my test I can drag and drop to change the task’s order in taskboard.

Besides, you can also set priority for each task to know which has the highest priority.

1. Sprints --> Configure team settings –-> Fields —-> Task –->
   Additional fields —-> Priority
2. Add priority , then you can know which task has the highest
   priority.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi Andy, thanks for responding. Are you sure you have the taskboard grouped by person? Thanks for the tip about the priority field, but dragging the priority is still prefered.